# Is this code undefined behavior due to accessing out of bound element in the first for loop?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Is this code undefined behavior due to accessing out of bound element in the first for loop?

```
int main() {
    std::size_t length = 4;
    int* a = new int[length];

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; )
        a[i] = ++i;
    for (std::size_t i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        std::cout << a[length - 1] << " ";
}
```

Comment: `=` is evaluated right to left, so it does access out of bounds.

Comment: @Ext3h: It seems odd that the C++ Standard mandated that the right-side value be computed before the left-side lvalue is resolved, since there are times where the most efficient way to perform the operation would be to resolve the left side first.  For example, given `a[externFunction()] = externScopeObject;`, requiring a compiler to evaluate `externScopeObject` before the function call would generally necessitate an otherwise-unnecessary push/pop cycle.

Answer (score 0):

If shrotly, yes, it is. In this situation C++ doesn't define in which order expression must be calculated, because both sides have side effects. So one compiler can firstly calculate left side, second can calculate at first right side. But if you look at [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), you can find that

```
a[i] = i++;       // undefined behavior until C++17
```

So, you can use this line, only if you use C++ 17.

Comment: So you agree that it is UB because of out or bound access and additionally say that it is also UB if I don't compile with C++17, right?

Comment: I think, that it UD behavior until C++ 17, because, we don't know order of evaluation, and everything may happen. C++ 17 define evaluation order, i try to find it.

Comment: `operator=` associativity is R to L, hence in c++17 the first assignment will be `a[1] = 1`, and the last on will be `a[4] = 4`, right?

Comment: Yes, i compile this function in Visual Studio, with language standart C++ 17, and i found, that in first loop we have assignment to a[4], in last iteration.

Comment: Also you have an error in second loop, cause of your variable i, is unsigned and try to became less than 0. And you enter into endless loop

Comment: I know, this is a test task and it is a wrong task. :)